# how to add ".then()" and ".catch()" to a lambda in javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm looking for making something like this in function.  The problem with this example is the .then() statement from then on.  (syntax problem).  How would I do issue the lambda with a "then" and "catch" sections?

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
    region: "us-west-2"
});
exports.my_func = async function(email) {

    const params = {
        FunctionName: funcion_name,
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        LogType: 'Tail',
        Payload: JSON.stringify(email)
    };


    lambda.invoke(params)
        .then(response => {
            const thing = other_function(response)
            return thing
        })
        .catch(err => {
            throw my_error(400, 'Not working '+ err);
        })
}
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

Comment: Close but not quite.  I'm not sure what to do with the "function(err, data)" part  of "lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {".

Answer (score 3):

You could use `.promise()`

```
const lambdaInvokePromise = params => lambda.invoke(params).promise()

// ...

lambdaInvokePromise(params)
  .then(response => {
    const thing = other_function(response)
    return thing
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw my_error(400, 'Not working ' + err)
  })
```

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
  region: 'us-west-2'
})

const lambdaInvokePromise = params => lambda.invoke(params).promise()

exports.my_func = async function(email) {
  const params = {
    FunctionName: funcion_name,
    InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
    LogType: 'Tail',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(email)
  }

  lambdaInvokePromise(params)
    .then(response => {
      const thing = other_function(response)
      return thing
    })
    .catch(err => {
      throw my_error(400, 'Not working ' + err)
    })
}
```

---

**Reference**

[Using Javascript Promise - AWS SDK for Javascript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use then/catch. You can use promise as already mentioned by @hgb123, but I would change the code slightly to use async/await since you're already in an async function.

```
try {
    const response = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
    return other_function(response)
} catch(e) {
    throw my_error(400, 'Not working '+ err);
}
```